# Threaded Python not running

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm trying to show a graphic. run multiple threads. when a thread finishes it updates the display.

`if threads[x].is_alive():` always returns False, even though the thread should run for a few seconds. Can anyone see why that is?

Thank you.

```
def run(cmd, result, index):
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

    process.wait()

    result[index] = str(process.communicate()).strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # create 5 jobs
    threads = [None] * 5
    results = [None] * 5

    for i in range(len(threads)):
        threads[i] = threading.Thread(target=run, args=([['hashcat', "-a", "0", "-m", "0", "./crackhash" + str(i+1) + ".txt", "rockyou.txt", "--force"], results, i]))
        threads[i].start()

    for i in range(len(threads)):
        threads[i].join()

...

    # 4 - keep looping through
    while 1:
        # 5 - clear the screen before drawing it again
        screen.fill(0)
        print(threads)

        # 6 - draw the screen elements
        # element 1
        if threads[0].is_alive():
            screen.blit(text_surface, (0,0))
            screen.blit(green_button, (x - x/9, 0))
        else:
            threat_output = results[0]
            answer = get_text(results[0], "./crackhash0.txt")
            text_surface_answer = my_font.render(answer, False, (255, 255, 0))
            screen.blit(text_surface_answer, (0,0))
            screen.blit(red_button, (x - x/9, 0))
...
```

update:

```
t1 = subprocess.Popen(['hashcat', "-a", "0", "-m", "0", "./crackhash0.txt", "rockyou.txt", "--force"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
t2 = subprocess.Popen(['hashcat', "-a", "0", "-m", "0", "./crackhash1.txt", "rockyou.txt", "--force"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

while 1:
    screen.fill(0)

    # check if t1 is still running
    t1_running = t1.poll()
    if t1_running is None:
        print("RUNNING")
```

Comment: if you `join` them, then it will wait for them to finish before proceeding

Comment: No need to use threads here. Just create `Popen` objects directly.

Comment: Expanding what Roland said: Your main program creates five threads, and then it does nothing until they all terminate. Each of the five threads creates one process and then does nothing until the process terminates. What's the benefit of the threads? Why does your main program not simply create five processes, and then wait for them?

Comment: you have to run `.join()` after loop `while 1:`.

Comment: Pygame is not thread-safe, meaning that it might be possible to change the display surface or drain the evvent queue from another thread than the main one.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot guys. I've updated my answer.. Is that basically what you're saying?